# get the value of the current counter

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

I'd like to recover the value of the current environment counter and store it for my own uses, e.g. in the example below I'd like to store (*not* print) the number 1.  With `\@currenvir` I can get the name of the current environment.  What is the most convenient way of getting the value of the counter of the environment that I'm in?

If I know that I'm in a `lemma`, like below, then the solution is easy, but I'm looking for a solution that is independent of the type of environment that I'm in.

(EDIT:) preferably something that works with the various packages that mess with the labeling system (`hyperref`, `cleveref`, `autoref`, etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\storecurrentlabelvalue}[1]{}


\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
blabla\storecurrentlabelvalue{\mylabelvalue}
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't count (!) on the environment name to have the same like the counter

Comment: Do you mean that `\thewhatever` need not produce the value of the counter of the `whatever` environment?  For what I have in mind I'm happy to make that assumption.

Comment: »the current environment counter« – not every environment has a counter associated! And it's `\@currenvir`. Something like the following? `\edef\foo{\the\value{\@currenvir}}` (or with `\xdef` for a global assignment) or `\setcounter{mycounter}{\value{\@currenvir}}`

Comment: But you probably want `\@currentlabel` which holds the current label text

Comment: @clemens: I rather believe it's the real counter value

Comment: I don't mind knowing both!

Comment: Isn't `\label` and `\ref` what you need?

Comment: NO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not every environment has a counter and even if it has got a counter, there is no guarantee that the counter has the same name like the environment (and vice versa).

This uses `\xpatchcmd{}` to hack into `\refstepcounter` (which is the labelling one) and defines `\mylabelvalue` as `\number\value{#1}`, `#1` being the counter name.

It does not interfere with `hyperref` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\xdef\mylabelvalue{}

\xpatchcmd{\refstepcounter}{%
  \stepcounter{#1}%
}{%
  \stepcounter{#1}%
  \xdef\mylabelvalue{\number\value{#1}}%
}{\typeout{success}}{\typeout{failure}}


\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
blabla
\end{lemma}

Value is \mylabelvalue


\begin{equation}
   E = mc^2
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
   E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   E = mc^2
\end{equation}


Value is \mylabelvalue



\end{document}
```

**Here is another version**

It uses my `assoccnt` package and the command `\LastRefSteppedCounter` and there's `\LastSteppedCounter` too.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{assoccnt}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}




\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
blabla
\end{lemma}

The last counter refstepped was \LastRefSteppedCounter\ and its value is  \number\value{\LastRefSteppedCounter}


\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

The last counter refstepped was \LastRefSteppedCounter\ and its value is  \number\value{\LastRefSteppedCounter}


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit** -- the successor package of `assoccnt` is `xassoccnt` and provides `\LastCounterValue` as new feature. I've uploaded `xassoccnt v0.6` to CTAN (recently), current version is `v1.5` already.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
blabla
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Other one
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}
Yet another one
\end{lemma}


The last counter refstepped was \LastRefSteppedCounter\ and its value is \LastCounterValue

\edef\storedlastvalue{\LastCounterValue}


\section{A section}

\section{Another section}

The last counter refstepped was \LastRefSteppedCounter\ and its value is \LastCounterValue

\subsection{Even deeper sectioning}

The last counter refstepped was \LastRefSteppedCounter\ and its value is \LastCounterValue\ contrary to \storedlastvalue

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the solution that uses the `assoccnt` package.

Comment: @Mico ;-) that's a buggy package from a buggy man... wait until `xassoccnt` appears ;-)

Comment: By the way: congrats on passing the 50K reputation points mark!!! Very well earned!!

Comment: @Mico: Thanks. Now I will edit your and egreg's answers (and his questions :-))

Comment: Having unlimited editing rights has its advantages! Just don't get carried away... :-)

Comment: Glad if I pushed you over the top; congrats regardless.